# Document code snippet feature

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, help-center, editing-help

When posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59868436/798371), I consulted [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) looking for the syntax needed for the snippet feature, which was mostly added in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59868436/3).

I reached that page by clicking "More" in the lower right corner of this screenshot, considering that snippets would be in the "More" category beyond "Links," "Images", "Code," etc.:
[image: Editor in context]

On that page, there aren't any such instructions and there is not even any mention of "snippet" in passing.  However, there is plenty of other content to indicate that if it were to be found, that still seems like the right place to be looking.

Can it please be added, as part of improvement on the [2nd most common top issue with SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/)?

Comment: It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Ivar Maybe that should be the target of the "more" link instead?